# How do I overlay text on a banner, and make it responsive to page size?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

my problem is that the "h1" text is not showing up, and when I resize the screen the "p" text moves down on the page, no longer on the image.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="home_header">
        <img src="resources/assets/home_header.png" alt="youth futures header">
        <h1>Hi</h1>
        <p class="textstyle2">14 WARM BEDS. YOUTH 12-17.<br/>YOUR TEMPORARY HOME:)</p>

</div>
```

here is the css

```
h1 {
font-family: "quicksand-bold";
font-size:214px;
line-height:244px;
color:#ffffff;
margin:0;
width: auto;
text-align:center;
}

.textstyle2 {
font-family:"quicksand-bold";
font-size:38px;
line-height:43px;
color:#9ec54d !important;
}
```

Comment: Since the image is not a full path all i see is white between the image and the p tags. The H1 is the same color as background (#ffffff). What CSS are you using to place the image as a background? If you the image to extend with smaller screensize then you will need an image with a bigger height, placed as a background on the div **OR** you can use media query to adjust the line-height, margin and padding around the h1 and paragraph tags on different screensizes.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS Code

```
.hero {
      width:960px;
      margin:1rem auto;
      position: relative;
    }

    .text {
      background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
      position: absolute;
      top:50%;
      left:0;
      padding:1rem;
      transform:translateY(-50%);

    }
```

And your HTML Code

```
<div class="hero">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-960-480-4.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="text">
   <h1>Hi</h1>
        <p class="textstyle2">14 WARM BEDS. YOUTH 12-17.<br/>YOUR TEMPORARY HOME:)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#home_header{position: relative;}` Position your container relative to the other elements and then position the elements inside it with

```
img, h1, p {
     position: absolute;
}
```

Now your div should have the same height with your image. Then adjust the positioning of your elements according to the container element `#home_header`. For instance if you want to keep the paragraph 10px above the bottom of the image:

```
p {bottom: 10px;}
```

If you want the `h1` at the top part of the image with a 10px margin:

```
h1 {top: 10px;}
```

If you want to keep them together assign another container element for `h1` and `p` and change its position relative to the `#home_header`

```
<div class="banner_text">
    <h1>...</h1>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

To center the text

```
.banner_text {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```